# Does Stack Overflow or Meta have a Killfile equivalent?

Tags: support

I see there is an old discussion on Meta.SE on [Add the ability to ignore users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3353/173448). It seems like that would be a useful feature at times.

Does Stack Overflow or Meta have a [Killfile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kill_file) equivalent? If so, where is it and how does one use it?

Comment: No.​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: ..But there is a [script](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3360/ignore-users-script) to do it. It's from 2009, but might still work.

Comment: I don't see any reason at all, why it should be usefull feature on stack.

Comment: I can see a use for this on the main site (especially in tags where the quality is persistently poor) but if you have a disagreement with someone, it is best not to be ignoring them. Meta is for solving problems about the site, and so it may be best not to ignore anyone here.

Comment: Hey, that's the first time my comments annoyed anybody so much that they opened a meta question on how to ignore me completely. But seriously, I was not attempting to troll or harrass you and apologize if it came across in this way. I do feel my comments were relevant, otherwise I wouldn't have written them.

Comment: @l4mpi - its not just you. The same [bikeshedding](http://bikeshed.com/) is taking place here: I asked if the feature was available; and the majority of people answered a different question (in the comments no less). In this case, it appears the question others are trying to answer is "should the feature be available". That was ***not*** the question I asked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Does Stack Overflow or Meta have a Killfile equivalent?

No. No Stack Exchange sites have anything like that.

> If so, where is it and how does one use it?

Since there isn't one... one can't use it ;)

---

There are no plans to add such a feature.

Comment: Thanks Oded. I'm sorry to hear there are no plans for it.